# JQuery-mobile validation!

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery-mobile under eclipse. I have a form with 2 text fields, I want my 1st text field in the form to be able accept only numbers, so if the input is a char, or text or even empty, i want an error to appear. as for validation goes, I am using jquery validVal. I have included my codes `

```
<form id="ccform" method = "post">
        <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="cc">Card Number</label></td>
             <td><input name = "ccc" class="required" type = "text" id = "cc" maxlength="23" " ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Card Holder Name</td>
    <td><input class="required" type = "text"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    </form>
```

and also:

```
<script>
    $("#ccform").validVal({
        customValidaton:{
            "cc": function ($field){
                var myexpr =/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/
                if(myexpr.test($field.val())) {return true;}
                else{return false;}
                }
            }
    });
    </script>

`
```

but I dont get any result, nothing... so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error. Your regular expression should start and end with a `/`.

`/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/`

Answer (score 2):

you can look at http://validval.frebsite.nl/examples.php.

See example 1, there is **validVal** validation available for number.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother writing your own validation?? Use an existing plugin such as [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

You can do like this.
first change the file as below. Note the Required number attribute.

`<input name = "ccc" class="required number" type = "text" id = "cc" maxlength="23">`

Then a simple `$("#ccform").validate();` can do the magic.

full working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/A3rvK/3/